# Primefaces upload multi file with umlaut

Tags: jsf, tomcat, primefaces

I am new to primefaces. I have implemented a web application with Tomcat.
The app includes also a page with single mode file upload and another with multi upload.

As i am using umlaut in the filenames they were sent to the backend in an "encrypted" format. To solve the issue i added to tomcat the config param: 
    -Dfile.encoding="ISO-8859-1"
and the form is something like this:

```
<h:form enctype="multipart/form-data" acceptcharset="ISO-8859-1">

....
```

This works fine for single mode upload. However the multi file does not! For the multi file i tried the form with and without acceptcharset="ISO-8859-1" property. But no results!!

What i am doing wrong? What i need to do to have BOTH upload modes working?
Any advice very much appreciated!

thanks lot!!

Comment: try using UTF_8 instead of ISO-8859-1.for glassfish server i always write something like that      in  glassfish-web.xml when the filename in Arabic

     <parameter-encoding default-charset="UTF-8"/>